# Easiest way to convert array to certain range values

Tags: python, image-processing

I have `2-d numpy array`which have values from `0` to `100` which denote position of pixel on image of size `100*100` .

`(0,0)` top left corner, `(100,100)` denote bottom right corner.

I want to convert these pixel co-ordinates such that coordinates are normalized.

```
(0,0) --> (-1,-1)
(0,100) --> (-1,1)
(100,0) --> (1,-1)
(100,100) --> (1,1)
(50,50) --> (0,0)
```

In nutshell I want to convert pixel coordinates into the values in between `-1` and `1` as above.

Comment: Can you please give an example of such an array? Is it a numpy array with two dimensions or does it contain tuples like in your example or is it a list of lists etc...

Comment: I have updated the question details. I am considering numpy 2-d array instead of tuple.

Comment: If `(x,y)` is your co-ordinate and want to transform to `(x', y')`. I think `x' = x/50 - 1` and `y' = y/50 - 1` should do.

Answer (score 2):

Should be easily done like this (a being a numpy array):

`(a - 50) / 50`